# Repeat audio clip in Unity, with increasingly smaller intervals

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer

I want a countdown timer to tick faster as the time counts down. the 'tick' is a very short audioclip.

I've got the timer working which calls playTickManager() every frame.

However with this implementation, at some transitions of cancel/re-invoke, the gap between ticks is inconsistent or overlaps causing an unnatural sounding tick.

Is there a better way to implement this without speeding up the actual audioclip, thus maintaining pitch etc?

```
// This is called every frame by the 'timer' script as it counts down to 0. 
// 'seconds' is a float.

void playTickManager()
{
    Debug.Log(seconds);
    if (seconds >= 20 && tickPlaySpeed != 1)
    {
        InvokeRepeating("playTickAudio", 1f, 1f);
        tickPlaySpeed = 1;
    }
    else if (seconds >= 16 && seconds < 20 && tickPlaySpeed != 2)
    {
        CancelInvoke("playTickAudio");
        InvokeRepeating("playTickAudio", 0f, .85f);
        tickPlaySpeed = 2;
    }
    else if (seconds >= 12 && seconds < 16 && tickPlaySpeed != 3)
    {
        CancelInvoke("playTickAudio");
        InvokeRepeating("playTickAudio", 0f, .7f);
        tickPlaySpeed = 3;
    }
    else if (seconds > 8 && seconds < 12 && tickPlaySpeed != 4)
    {
        CancelInvoke("playTickAudio");
        InvokeRepeating("playTickAudio", 0f, .55f);
        tickPlaySpeed = 4;
    }
    else if (seconds >= 4 && seconds < 8 && tickPlaySpeed != 5)
    {
        CancelInvoke("playTickAudio");
        InvokeRepeating("playTickAudio", 0f, .4f);
        tickPlaySpeed = 5;
    }
    else if (seconds > 0 && seconds < 3 && tickPlaySpeed != 6)
    {
        CancelInvoke("playTickAudio");
        InvokeRepeating("playTickAudio", 0f, .25f);
        tickPlaySpeed = 6;
    }
    else if(seconds <= 0)
    {
        CancelInvoke("playTickAudio");
        tickPlaySpeed = 0;
    }
}

void playTickAudio()
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(tickAudio, gameObject.transform.position, 1f);
}
```

Comment: What is the min and max of the countdown? How many seconds apart is the first tick?

Comment: min =0, max is whatever is passed in. The Timer script just does the following on Update 'timeleft = timeleft-Time.timeDelta; playTickManager();'

Comment: Important point here.  @mbka ... never, ***EVER***, use "else if" for any reason.  It's rather like using "globals" in software - never do it.

Comment: Why is that? I believe usually it's not recommended to else if nest due to readability and complexity? In this example above, doesn't it help stop the if tree when a condition is found; compared to multiple 'if' that are all evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good chance to learn a very common pattern.

This is the ***"call yourself again"*** pattern in software.

Note that this is very, very common in games - notably every type of **weapon** uses the "call yourself again" pattern.  (In short, you don't use something like "invokeRepeating" since you need more control over the firing loop.)

So try this ... teaching example:

```
private float gapToNext;

private void ExcitingCountdown()
  {
  gapToNext = 2.5f;
  PlayOneStep();
  }

private void PlayOneStep()
  {
  if (gapToNext < 0.01f) return;
  YourBeepSound.Play();
  gapToNext = gapToNext - 0.1f;
  Invoke("ExcitingCountdown", gapToNext);
  }
```

Simple right?

## Life is easier when you know the patterns  :)

Note that in reality, your code would look like this:

Just adjust the values in `ExcitingCountdown` to get the sounding result you want.

```
private float gapToNext;
private int safetyCounter;

void Start()
  {
  ExcitingCountdown();
  }

private void ExcitingCountdown()
  {
  gapToNext = 2.5f;
  safetyCounter = 30;
  PlayOneStep();
  }

private void PlayOneStep()
  {
  if (gapToNext < 0.05f || safetyCounter<0)
    {
    Debug.Log("we're done...!");
    return;
    }
  
  YourBeepSound.Play();
  
  gapToNext = gapToNext * 0.85f;
  --safetyCounter;

  Debug.Log("gap is now " +gapToNext.ToString("f4"));

  Invoke("ExcitingCountdown", gapToNext);
  }
```

Comment: So if I understand your 2nd block of code correctly - every loop, it reduces the gapToNext by 15% until it hits <0.05f then stops. So each Beep interval is 15% smaller until it ends, or has completed 30 iterations. Let me try to implement this and see how I go.

Comment: @JoeBlow you need at least 15 rep to vote up, however now that I upvoted the OP (it was a decent question) he should be able to do it now.

Comment: Implemented this @JoeBlow, and it works. Thanks ! Have a different issue now with the audioclip reference but I'll post that in a different question.

Comment: hi @mbka!  pls make a link on this page to your new question, so I can see it also cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968839/unity3d-script-losing-audioclip-reference-when-using-addcomponent