# Unity3d script losing AudioClip reference when using AddComponent()

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have script (#2) below with a public AudioClip variable. When I 'addComponent', it loses that reference.

I've tested manually adding it to an object in the editor, and in that case it works OK. Why does my script added during runtime lose the reference?

GameObject 1: has this script (#1) attached

```
void HitByRay() {
    clock = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Clock_Arrow").GetComponent<Clock>();
    clock.gameObject.AddComponent<Tick_Audio_Script>();
}
```

Which attaches the following script (#2) to the 'Clock' object.

```
public int safetyCounter;
float gapToNext;
public AudioClip tickAudio;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    startTicker(100);
}

void startTicker(int maxTicks)
{
    safetyCounter = maxTicks;
    gapToNext = 1f;
    playTick();

}

void playTick()
{
    Debug.Log("Tick");
    if (gapToNext < 0.1 || safetyCounter == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("We're done...!");
        return;
    }
// **ERROR HERE CLIP NOT FOUND** 
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(tickAudio, gameObject.transform.position, 1f);

    gapToNext = gapToNext * 0.97f;
    safetyCounter--;
    Invoke("playTick",gapToNext);
}
```

Here's the script in the editor, where I've assigned the audioclip.
[image: In the Editor]

But when it's attached via 'AddComponent', the reference to that clip does not come through (after I hit play and 'hit' my trigger object which attaches this script)? This results in a null reference error as there is no clip found to be played.

[image: After addComponent]

My AudioListener (located on a different object) is working, as there are other sounds being played correctly in the scene.

Again, I've tested adding this  script manually to any object pre-run in the editor it works. Why is this?

Comment: Hi MBKA.  You make it difficult by not including the full code, because, I can't see what the hell the classes are called and so on.  Apart from that please read this: are you saying that it does't appear IN THE EDITOR, WHEN YOU ARE JUST "SITTING THERE" BETWEEN PLAYING?  if so that's correct.  only once you actually Play! will it run the code and find the value.

Comment: dude you DEFINITELY should not name it Tick_Audio_Script.  It's just TickAudio.cs.  Never use underscores, for any reason ever.  And never put "script" in a script name.

Comment: That is the full code for now, though I plan to add more to script #1 later (do other stuff when hit).  I've placed the actual startTicker in a separate script as various interactions may trigger that. To clarify - the first image is the script in my project window. Then 2nd image is after I've hit 'play' and 'hit' the trigger object which attaches TickAudio script - this results in a null reference error (as the script didn't keep the reference and has no audioclip to play). Hope that clears it up !

Comment: Point taken on naming convention ! :)

Comment: its not the full code, you didn't include "Class ... blah" etc.  Anyway no worries.

Comment: I don't even understand how you created Image1 ... what version of Unity is this???

Comment: Ah ok you're right. Will copy the entire thing next time ! Unity 5.3.5, it's a screen grab from the inspector when selecting my script. 2nd image is the actual clock object inspector. I can see how it's not too clear. Will also take a wider screenshot next time.

Comment: I don't mean the photo is unclear: what I mean is, normally unity doesn't let you select those in there.  Anyways - the problem is solved, I'll look for the next one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a simple solution. You can do one of the following:

1) Create a prefab and add it to "clock" with the needed references.

2) do this:

```
void HitByRay() {
    clock = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Clock_Arrow").GetComponent<Clock>();
    clock.gameObject.AddComponent<Tick_Audio_Script>();
//NEW PART
    clock.gameObject.GetComponent<Tick_Audio_Script>().TickAudio = (desired Audio);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried method 2. That works ! But what's the issue? If I wanted that script to have a default sound shouldn't my initial implementation work? I don't understand what's fundamentally incorrect about it.

Comment: only if you create a prefab item :). Read this article to learn more http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html

Comment: So adding a reference to the script itself only works on scripts which are attached in the editor (e.g. on a prefab), whereas scripts attached at runtime lose that reference? I get it in practice, but am still curious as to the why it works that way.

Comment: This is because you get the script as it is (from the project window). Is how unity works. However, if you are using the same audio clip always you could set it in the Tick_Audio_Script on Start(). But again, this only works if the audio clip doesn't change.

Comment: When you have multiple lines of code on this website highlight the code and press the `{ }` on the toolbar, don't put it in backticks, it looks a lot better if you do it with the `{ }` button.

Comment: Also, instead of calling `.AddComponent<Tick_Audio_Script>()` then immediately doing `.GetComponent<Tick_Audio_Script>()`, just use `Tick_Audio_Script script = clock.gameObject.AddComponent<Tick_Audio_Script>(); script.TickAudio = (desired Audio);`