# How to subtract timestamps using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in C# unity i want to do time minus time.
I have an example below :

```
Time1:
int Hour = 12;
int Minutes = 0;
Int Seconds = 0;

Time2:
int LastHour = 1;
int LastMinutes = 3;
int LastSeconds = 20;
```

Actually i want that the result is like below :

```
Result:
int ResultHour = 10;
int ResultMinutes = 56;
int ResultSeconds = 40;
```

If Time1 - Time2 it Will get Like Result

How to do it in C# unity ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in a video game ?

Comment: @Dennis Liu  Considering your other question, you would be storing UNIX timestamp, you were misled by turning into TimeSpan, you don't need it. Just subtract your new timestamp and the old timestamp, check if the result is bigger than a certain period (60 for a minute, 3600 for an hour and so on) and this is it.

Comment: Yes @JoeBlow, Because i want to calculate the timer. For example : If when i play timer start at 00:00:60 then when play the timer start countdown 00:00:59 00:00:58 00:00:57 00:00:56 00:00:55 and then i exit the game. Then i delay to play for 3 seconds. When i play after 3 seconds the timer start countdown from 00:00:52 00:00:51 00:00:50.

Comment: hi Dennis. you just use Invoke.  (perhaps InvokeRepeating also)   it is very easy!

Comment: here .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35807346/294884

Comment: here ... . http://stackoverflow.com/a/37944881/294884

Comment: Invoke repeating is not relevant here as he wants tone do it over different sessions.

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow, recently question that i make was duplicate, so i change the question. Is it right or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) structure:

```
var time1 = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
var time2 = new TimeSpan(10, 56, 40);

var result = time1 - time2; // will be 01:03:20
```

To get the specific time parts, access the `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` properties of `result`.

Answer (score 1):

TimeSpan is you way:

```
TimeSpan result = (new TimeSpan(Hour, Minutes, Seconds)
                 - new TimeSpan(LastHour, LastMinutes, LastSeconds));

int ResultHour = result.Hours;
int ResultMinutes = result.Minutes;
int ResultSeconds = result.Seconds;
```